# Syntax error creating variables within loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, syntax, index-error

I'm trying to create variables within these loops but python gives me a syntax error. `tme` and `empty` both give me this problem. I'm trying to get python to read an excel sheet and put the values in a list. The variables I'm trying to create are supposed to help me find the empty spaces in python and remove the value from another list I created so that the values I obtain correspond to the correct input and the inputs that have no value in excel are removed from that list. It gives an index error too if there's a fix for that I'd appreciate it, but I can figure that out if the variables work correctly.

```
span = list()
print(span)
price = list() #creates a list with all the values before giving index error
for q in range(1,chart.nrows):
    for i in range (1,chart.ncol):
        L = (chart.cell_value(q,i))
        if L != '': #all values that exist will be appended to the list
            price.append(L)
        else: #find x and y parts of space, have that popped from span list
            moth = chart.cell_value(q,0)
            m = str(moth)
            y = year = str(chart.cell_value(0,i)
            tme = m + ' ' + y
            empty = span.index(tme)
            span.pop(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from a syntax point of view you were missing a closing bracket in

```
y = year = str(chart.cell_value(0,i))
```